# whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The JS file 'drf-yasg\redoc\redoc.min.js' references a file which could not be found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg, whitenoise

I tried collecting static files on an API project I am working with Django/Django REST Framework and I got this error on my console. What could be the cause of the error?

raise processed
whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The
file 'drf-yasg/redoc/redoc.standalone.js.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x000002DEED19E050>.

The JS file 'drf-yasg\redoc\redoc.min.js' references a file which could not be found:
drf-yasg/redoc/redoc.standalone.js.map

Please check the URL references in this JS file, particularly any
relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Wbr.png)

Answer (score 5):

I have figured out the cause of this error. I was working with Django==4.0, I had to downgrade it to Django==3.2.9 and the error disappeared.

Comment: Also you can check here for drf-yasg: https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/761